# How javascript callbacks knows what are their parameters?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback

Imagine I have the following scenario:

```
var dataset = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(a) { return a;});
```

I fail to understand how exactly javascript knows I'm dealing with data, is it related on how the *.text* method is defined?

I then read this [article](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) and got even more confused, because it doesn't work in my case. Given that code:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(err, data) { return data;});
```

My output is:

```
0

1

2

3

4
```

So my question is: what is the convention? How is it implemented?

Comment: I don't think so... He is asking about method chaining, which is used in my question but it is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
.text(function(err, data) { return data;});
```

code should be:

```
.text(function(data, index) { return data;});
```

because d3 callbacks give data as first input and index as second input in the function.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8h0maLn/1/

Answer (score 1):

in the .text() method there will be 
`callback.apply(this,[this.err,this.someData])`
"this" would be referring to the d3 prototype